# Google Maps Info Window Styling Won't update

Tags: google-maps

I have put together a map using some code from the Google Maps API 3.0 and some code from the Fusion tables 'wizard'. In my website, the map's markers update immediately any new address data in the fusion table but the info window (whether customised or using the automatic option in Fusion Tables) does not. What is missing here?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDOQ7cOkzKuRSXdaZnJjmzf286-rU9Tb1w"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var defaultCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.514462083331054, -0.16631473222648907);
        var defaultZoom = 9;
        var tableId = '1gBco4IwW3QVelKt9fpY11auhGnm-bu-fNe_9bbvv';
        var locationColumn = 'col4';
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: defaultCenter,
            zoom: defaultZoom,
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            scrollwheel: false
        });
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP


        var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            query: {
                select: locationColumn,
                from: tableId
            },
            map: map
        });

        var zoomToAddress = function() {
            var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
            geocoder.geocode({
                address: address
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    map.setZoom(13);

                } else {
                    window.alert('Address could not be geocoded: ' + status);
                }
            });
        };

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('search'),'click', zoomToAddress);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'keypress', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                zoomToAddress();
            }
        });
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('reset'),
            'click',
            function() {
                map.setCenter(defaultCenter);
                map.setZoom(defaultZoom);
                layer.setOptions({
                    query: {
                        select: locationColumn,
                        from: tableId
                    }
                });
            });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly didn't update? The values of the row that will be printed in the infowindow or the selected columns that will be printed  when you change the InfoWindow-template?

Comment: It's the selected columns that won't update to reflect any customisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the `templateId` , otherwise the InfoWindow will be created based on the default-template(with all columns)

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(
    {
        query:
        {
            select: locationColumn,
            from: tableId
        },
        options:
        {   //a custom template 
            //created by someone
            //which omits the 'Household Street'
            templateId: 3
        },
        map: map
    });
```